# SSIS package runs very slow with sql agent job

Tags: sql, ssis, agent

We created a ssis package that takes approximately 10mins to run in visual studio and even when manually run in ssms manually. But when we run it from sql agent job, it goes from 10 mins to over an hour. We created a new job and attached it to the package. It ran 10 mins when the developer of the ssis package runs the sql agent job but when any other user runs the agent it takes over an hour. Any help would be grestly appericated.

Comment: How are you running the job manually in SSMS?  Also, please provide more details about how the sql agent job is configured, where the package is located, what it's connecting to and what it is doing.

Comment: Does the agent job use the same source/target systems as the manual runs? What activities are going on in the source/target systems when the package is running? What does the SSIS package do? Where is it spending the time? Does this run in the Integration Services catalog, msdb, or the file system?

Comment: @Robert3000- I have been facing same problem. Running the package manually from command prompt using dtexec is fast and from SQL agent it is so slow. Did you ever find out anything?